# How do you retrieve a value from IndexedDB when using serviceworkers?

Tags: javascript, html, service-worker, indexeddb

I am new to IndexedDB and serviceworkers and am having a very difficult time understanding how to turn these into a funcitonal application. I've done extensive reading on both, but even the "complete" examples don't incorporate the two.

I am tasked with creating an application that will allow users to work offline. The first time they connect to the site, I want to pull specific information from the database and store it in IndexedDB. When they go offline, I need to use that data to display information on the page. Certain interactions will cause the data to update, then to be synced later once an internet connection is reestablished. From a high-level, I udnerstand how this works.

It is my understanding that we cannot call functions from the serviceworker.js file due to the asynchronous nature of serviceworkers. Additionally, serviceworkers.js cannot directly update the DOM. However, the examples I have seen are creating and managing the IndexedDB data within the serviceworkers.js file.

So let's say I have a file:

```
<!-- index.html -->
<html>
<body>
Hello <span id="name"></span>
</body>
</html>
```

And a serviceworker.js:

```
var CACHE_NAME = 'my-cache-v1';
var urlsToCache = [
    '/'
    // More to be added later
];

self.addEventListener('install', function(event) {
  // Perform install steps
  event.waitUntil(
    caches.open(CACHE_NAME)
      .then(function(cache) {
        console.log('Opened cache');
        return cache.addAll(urlsToCache);
      })
  );
});


self.addEventListener('activate', function(event) {
  event.waitUntil(
    createDB() //Use this function to create or open the database
  );
});

self.addEventListener('fetch', function(event) {
  event.respondWith(
    caches.match(event.request)
      .then(function(response) {
        // Cache hit - return response
        if (response) {
          return response;
        }

        return fetch(event.request).then(
          function(response) {
            // Check if we received a valid response
            if(!response || response.status !== 200 || response.type !== 'basic') {
              return response;
            }
            
            var responseToCache = response.clone();

            caches.open(CACHE_NAME)
              .then(function(cache) {
                cache.put(event.request, responseToCache);
              });

            return response;
          }
        );
      })
    );
});

function createDB() {
  idb.open('mydata', 1, function(upgradeDB) {
    var store = upgradeDB.createObjectStore('user', {
      keyPath: 'id'
    });
    store.put({id: 1, name: 'John Doe'}); //This can be updated with an AJAX call to the database later
  });
}
```

How do I now update the element "name" with the value for key = 1 from the "user" objectstore in the "mydata" database?

Comment: You don't need service worker for this thing.Service Workers is designed to cache the static HTML, CSS, JavaScript, and image files in cache storage. I would suggest give this a try. https://pouchdb.com/

Comment: I am caching HTML, CSS, and JavaScript as well (that works fine). IndexedDB is the service I have been told to use.

Comment: try the link which i have provided here, that s library is what you need.https://pouchdb.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your use case, you've got several options :

1. You dont need the service worker. Just pull your data from iDB directly from the page. The DOM has access to iDB.
2. Set a template for your index.html. At the activate step in service worker, pre-render the page with the value from iDB and cache it.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I had a team give me an old, prototype portion of the code that included IDB in ServiceWorkers. It seems to me to make way more sense to keep IDB separate from ServiceWorkers. I can still use ServiceWorkers to cache the CSS and JS, and use IDB to store the data from the database... I'll just go that route. 

Hadn't thought of #2 at all - good idea. Just more work.